# no module named pyfiglet.fonts failed to execute script due to unhandled exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently compiled a .py file to an application and the .py works fine but the application gives me this error `no module named pyfiglet.fonts`
`failed to execute script '' due to unhandled exception`
then closes immediately

The modules im using :

```
from colorama import Fore
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pyfiglet
from colorama import Fore
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to missing package/ incorrect virtual env being used to run the program.

you can verify the package's installation by running *pip freeze* in the terminal if you are not using an IDE in the first place.

Comment: @Cre Then the package is not an issue, are you using pyfiglet.fonts at any point directly in the code ?

Comment: em im using 
 print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + pyfiglet.figlet_format('MultiTool', justify='center'))